# Display only not-DONE-yet items in agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have several agenda commands set up, one of which gives me a block agenda, others give me specific searches.

Since many of my TODOs are hanging around inside of projects, where I only archive the project when the whole thing is done, my system always has a bunch of DONE items hanging around.  So many of my searches result in screens that are 60-80% DONE items, with some TODOs scattered among them.

What I want to do, is to filter it out so I only see non-DONE items in these searches.

I've done web searches and read the manual and tutorials and used C-h, all in vain.

What I did manage to figure out is that the answer is probably in the settings field in `org-agenda-custom-commands`... but I seem to be unable to find documentation about that, that is good enough to help me figure it out.

Please will someone point me in the right direction here.

How do I make `org-agenda-custom-commands` show me only non-DONE items?

My current setup for that variable is as follows:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  (quote
   (("d" "Daily Planning Agenda + Next Actions"
 ((agenda ""
      ((org-agenda-span
        (quote day))))
  (tags "URGENT" nil "mygtd.org")
  (todo "WAITING" nil)
  (todo "STARTED" nil)
  (todo "TODO" nil))
 nil)
("h" tags "@home")
("w" tags "@work" nil)
("o" tags "@onlinebanking" nil)
("e" tags "@errands" nil)
("f" . "Agendas with individuals and groups")
("fh" "H..." tags "AGENDA=\"H... W...\"" nil)
("fH" "H..." tags "AGENDA=\"H... B...\"" nil)
("fl" "L..." tags "AGENDA=\"L... M...\"" nil)
("fp" "P..." tags "AGENDA=\"P... S...\"" nil)
("fm" "M..." tags "AGENDA=\"M... M...\"" nil)
("fr" "R..." tags "AGENDA=\"R... B...\"" nil)
("fM" "M..." tags "AGENDA=\"M... P...\"" nil))))
```

Comment: Can you post your `org-agenda-custom-commands` value?

Comment: Rather than org-agenda-custom-commands you might be better off if you read the info for org-stuck-projects.

Comment: @Tyler done - see the original question

Comment: @m43cap no that doesn't help. The searches that bother me most, are the ones that turn up TODOs to discuss with a particular person. I talk to many of them every week, and quite often their agenda becomes littered with things that was done a long time ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked:

> How do I make `org-agenda-custom-commands` show me only non-DONE items?

You can add `-TODO=\"DONE\"` to the **match** string of your tag search.
This is described in the seciton [11.3.3. Matching tags and properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties) of the Org manual. There is even an example there which contains the string `-TODO​="DONE"`. So you can search for it there.

The following example demonstrates that match string. It is marked by the comment `;; match`.

```el
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
     '("x" ;; key
       "Testing tags for negating DONE" ;; desc
       tags ;; type
       "-TODO=\"DONE\"" ;; match
       nil ;; settings
       nil ;; no files
       ))
```

Comment: Thank you @Tobias!  I have to confess, I wish there was a way to say that once, for the whole variable - now I have to add this string to each new entry I make in there.  Well, I'm not complaining too loudly - this works!

Comment: That's nice @Tobias.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a `tags` type agenda, which shows all entries regardless of TODO state, use a `tags-todo` type which only shows non-closed TODO items.  If you need a `tags` view so you can also see entries without a keyword, add `-TODO="DONE"` to your query.

For an `agenda` type view, the relevant variables are: `org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done`, `org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done`, `org-agenda-skip-timestamp-if-done`.  Setting these to `t` will had the corresponding entries from your agenda.

Comment: Thanks!  Useful info in here.  I use a PROPERTIES entry called AGENDA to store the name of the relevant person though, so (I think) I have to use a tags search to get the primary thing done ("show me only the things I need to talk to Alice about")

Comment: "use a tags-todo type which only shows non-closed TODO items." ?
There is no such a info in emacs:
"org-agenda-custom-commands is a variable defined in ‘org-agenda.el’.,,,
tags        Tags/Property/TODO match in all agenda files.
tags-todo   Tags/P/T match in all agenda files, TODO entries only.